# Query to list all the database in DB2

Tags: db2

The general CLP command for listing the databases in DB2
"LIST ACTIVE DATABASES"
what is the sql command to list all the database in a system directory?

Answer (score 2):

It is

```
list db directory
```

Details are documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001961.html)

Comment: can you say how to use that command in python code?

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in a comment!  To read the Db2 system database directory in python see an example here https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/python_samples/Jupyter_Notebooks/ibm_db_tools.py

Answer (score 0):

Using Python :

```
In [42]: stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "SELECT DISTINCT(DB_NAME) FROM table(mon_get_memory_pool('','',-2))")

In [43]: while (ibm_db.fetch_row(stmt)):
    ...:     DB_NAME = ibm_db.result(stmt, "DB_NAME")
    ...:     print("DB_NAME = {}".format(DB_NAME))
    ...: 
    ...: 
DB_NAME = SAMPLE
DB_NAME = None
```